# Cygwin chmod failing with path, working after cd

Tags: path, cygwin, windows-7-x64, chmod

Windows 7, 64-bit, Genuine Intel. NTFS. SSD, fwiw.

C:\SVN\zFPE610>uname -r
1.7.35(0.287/5/3)

If I do a chmod with a path, it says it worked, but doesn't. If I cd into the directory first, it works. Bulleted lines are my comments (I had 'em as asterisks, the site editor is making them into bullets):

- OK, i'm in C:\SVN\zFPE610:

C:\SVN\zFPE610>cat ZFP-BUILD-2015-03-27-001\Updated\VSHPCRT1
cat: ZFP-BUILD-2015-03-27-001\Updated\VSHPCRT1: Permission denied

- Let's chmod:

C:\SVN\zFPE610>chmod -v 777 C:/SVN/zFPE610/ZFP-BUILD-2015-03-27-001/Updated/*
mode of 'C:/SVN/zFPE610/ZFP-BUILD-2015-03-27-001/Updated/VSHPCRT1' changed from 0644 (rw-r--r--) to 0777 (rwxrwxrwx)

- Nope:

C:\SVN\zFPE610>cat ZFP-BUILD-2015-03-27-001\Updated\VSHPCRT1
cat: ZFP-BUILD-2015-03-27-001\Updated\VSHPCRT1: Permission denied

- Let’s look:

C:\SVN\zFPE610>ls -l ZFP-BUILD-2015-03-27-001/Updated/*
----rwx---+ 1 phsiii None 6800 Mar 27 15:24 ZFP-BUILD-2015-03-27-001/Updated/VSHPCRT1

- That sneaky chmod lied!
- Let's go to the directory:

C:\SVN\zFPE610>cd C:/SVN/zFPE610/ZFP-BUILD-2015-03-27-001/Updated/

- Nope, as expected:

C:\SVN\zFPE610\ZFP-BUILD-2015-03-27-001\Updated>cat VSHPCRT1
cat: VSHPCRT1: Permission denied

- Now let's chmod again from there:

C:\SVN\zFPE610\ZFP-BUILD-2015-03-27-001\Updated>chmod 777 *

- Hey, it worked!

C:\SVN\zFPE610\ZFP-BUILD-2015-03-27-001\Updated>cat VSHPCRT1
¦Q¦@@X¦¦^G¦¦b¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦a¦¦a¦¦¦¦K¦¦@@@Ö¦¦¦¦¦¦¦@¦¦¦¦`¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦@@¦8@@¦8@@
X¦??X¦ ¦¦?¦ ?!A0?¦.Q¦  ¦?¦?¦dA?¦?? ? ¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦@  ¦@@ 8@@ ??¦I Q¦? P¦¦¦¦

This happens whether I use a Windows- or UNIX-style path. I've tried using /cygwin/c/... as the path and that doesn't work either. Lots of searching finds tons of chmod problems but all seem related to not using NTFS or other things. And chmod *does* work when I'm in the directory, which is even weirder.

Before I got down to chmod, I had made sure I had full Windows permissions on the directory, too. The only thing that seems odd there is that I have "special" permissions as well; when I click Advanced, it agrees there are special permissions, but when I drill down in the dialogs, I don't see anything except regular (full) permissions.

Ideas?

Comment: you could check path character length?

Comment: Good thought, but it happens with C:\temp too. If THAT'S too long...!